# Unit testing laravel package using jenkins

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, jenkins, laravel-4

I have created a package in Laravel 4 and uploaded it to github. How can I automate the unit testing using Jenkins CI as laravel package doesn't have vendor folder pused to github.

Comment: There is [good guide](https://modess.io/continuous-integration-for-laravel-with-jenkins-and-git/) with boilerplate for integration 4th version of Laravel with git and Jenkins.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov thanks, I have gone through this guide and used it for my laravel application but when creating a laravel package it doesnt have the vendor folder so it is unable cannot run unit-tests

Comment: Okay then, did you tried [testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) package?

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov yes I have tried it and in my local its possible because I have the vendor folder with the dependencies, but in github I am not pushing my vendor folder so jenkins is unable to do automatic unit-testing.